# Strange filenames with embedded slashes - Mac/Windows conflict

Tags: java, windows, macos, zip, filenames

I wrote some code this week to generate zip files, and tried to use it on both Windows and Mac machines. Mac works fine (it was written with Mac in mind) but Windows less so. The resulting zip files, when opened on my Mac, contains a single level of files that look like this:

[image: Filenames, as viewed through a Mac.]

Rather than the expected nested filesystem of flash_out/assets, etc. I'm not hugely concerned about how to fix the code that generated these, but I am rather bothered about fixing these particular files so I can compile them on my mac. As it stands, I can't use these.

The strange thing is that opening up this zip on a Windows machine does indeed interpret this as a series of nested folders with files in. But zipping that file system up and sending it back to the Mac, the problem persists. I've not seen anything quite like this before.

Comment: Which zip tool did you use to create the file on the PC? Which zip tool are you using on the Mac?

Comment: Filenames are stored inside ZIP archive with '\' slashes, and Mac OS allows such slashes in filenames. Which library you used to generate zip files, and what tool you are using to unzip?

Comment: Java was used to create the ZIP on the Windows machine. Mac is unzipping using the default 'double-click to decompress' function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the bash shell, cd into the folder with the garbled filepaths, and try this:

```
for badfile in *\\*; do
    goodfile="${badfile//\\//}"
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$goodfile")"
    mv "$badfile" "$goodfile"
done
```